# can i change the value of comment settings in Drupal 6?

Tags: nodes, entities, comments

I have a default value of comment settings as 'read-write' but i want to set it to disable. I change this in administer >> content >> content types. But when i wanna create a node, the bloc of comment setting does not appear!! I want to have disable as default value and appear the box such that the user can choose the value that he likes. Can anyone help me please? Thanks

Comment: This does appear. Any other module conflicting this?